# What Class of Interactions, excluding spontaneous pair creation, Entangle two particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, non-linear-schroedinger

Un-Entangled particles have state vector: $|\psi\rangle = |p_1, p_2\rangle$, while entangled particles have a composite state vector    $|\psi\rangle = 1√2(|p_1,p_2\rangle\pm |p^\prime_1,p^\prime_2\rangle$). If we were talking about electron spin, for example, we might have the composite state written in the familiar way: $|S\rangle = 1√2 (|↑↓\rangle − |↓↑\rangle$). Any linear operator L (interaction) operating on $|\psi\rangle$ leaves states $|p_1\rangle$, $|p_2\rangle$ unmixed (un-entangled). This is the case for two photons colliding in the (linear) vacuum. However, two photons colliding in a non-linear crystal can produce a mixed or entangled state. The question is: Is a non-linear interaction required to entangle two particles? Electron/Positron pair creation produces an entangled pair, but does Compton scattering in a vacuum? In general, can anyone give an explicit type of interaction (nonlinear?) required for entanglement of two particles? Explicit examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here seems to be a mix of classical and quantum terminology. You discuss the most famous multi-particle system with no entanglement (neglecting the [Schwinger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect)), which is a pair of photons in the vacuum. Maxwell's equations don't tell us about entanglement directly but, because the equations are linear, they do tell us that wave packets of light cannot interact. Contrast this with two electrons in a Helium atom. These are interacting and this is captured by the fact that the classical equation of motion describing them is non-linear.

So what happens at the quantum level? Well again, two photons don't interact and two electrons do but how does one see this from the Schroedinger equation? It is always linear after all. Quantum mechanics is a linear theory for how the wavefunction evolves but in general it has to be a joint wavefunction. So what matters here is whether the Schroedinger equation can be solved by separation of variables. Whenever the answer is yes, that will be because it comes from a Hamiltonian which has no interactions and therefore gives linear classical equations. Whenever the answer is no, a product of free Hamiltonian eigenstates will inevitably evolve towards a state which cannot be written as a product.

So my answer is that all interactions produce entanglement and one should never call an interaction linear.

**Edit**:
To expand on the statement that interactions are non-linear... a non-linear crystal, as you know, mediates interactions between photons that enter it. That is not to say that so called linear crystals are completely invisible. Photons will interact with them of course, but the interaction will be such that the only significant entanglement produced is "crystal-to-photon", not "photon-to-photon".